# Reading a local csv file in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, csv, javascript-objects

I've written the following app to display a local csv file in the form of cards(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-card-slider-component) , but I'm getting an error with file system module (Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs')

Doing the following didn't help : `import fs from "fs";`

Here's my code :

```
import fs from "fs";
import ReactCardSlider from 'react-card-slider-component';
function App(){
  const sliderClick = (slider)=>{
    alert("hello world");
  }
  const fs = require('fs');
  const data = fs.readFileSync('F:/result.csv', 'utf8');
  console.log(data);

  var csv = require('jquery-csv');
  var slides = csv.toObjects(data);

return (
  <div id="body">
  <ReactCardSlider slides={slides}/>
  </div>);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: fs is node module. If you want to access files do it using `<input type="file">

Comment: @AzizHakberdiev but I'm not uploading the file , I'm using a local file

Answer (score 0):

browsers does not allow you to interact directly with files in the system like node.js, but you can use libraries that use the browser file system api, like [browser-fs-access](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/browser-fs-access) and [browserfs](https://github.com/jvilk/browserfs)

Comment: so all I have to add is ```const BrowserFS = require('browserfs')``` right ?
or should I install this with npm ?

browser fs access seems a bit complicated , how do I access a particular file from it ? like 'F:/result.csv' here

Comment: you cant access directly the file by its path, you need action from the user to open it , here is a nice tutorial about it https://web.dev/file-system-access/

Comment: Thank you , but I was looking for ways to output as cards. Can json file be read in this way or is it the same with every file present locally ?

Comment: you can read files normally  , but need to open first the folder by the user , imagine if it was possible to directly to refer a file without the user action, anyone could access you system files from the browser

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as fs from "fs"
//if CommonJS
const fs = require("fs")
```

Comment: tried , didn't work

Comment: I really do not understand wheter this code is running in node or browser. You put nodejs tag, but the answer above is suggesting you solution for browser

Comment: I'm using npm , but I'm unable to use fs to display data on the browser. The above answer wasn't of any help either. I resorted to using json file and now the error is resolved.